# American equivalent of "Flabbergasted"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I love to use the word "flabbergasted" when writing, but I realize I cannot really use it when it's an American talking, as the word is primarily used by British people. I know there's words like "shocked" and "surprised", but I want something with more flavor. The sentence I intend to use it in is; "The taxi driver seemed *flabbergasted* when I refused to tip him". Any American-english words with the same definition and flavor as that word is desired.

Comment: As an American, I'm flabbergasted to hear that the word isn't used in American English. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Well, I did say primarily used by British people. But since you, an American, say you're flabbergasted by me saying so, I guess it is also used a lot by Americans. If so, I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: _Flabbergasted_ is perhaps less common in AmE (though it’s not particularly common in BrE either), but it’s perfectly understandable, and there’s no reason for you not to use it just because the setting in American.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I was misled by my English teacher telling us that it was British slang used by old people.

Comment: Curiously, Google Books shows a wider usage in AmE vs  BrE. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flabbergasted%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cflabbergasted%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflabbergasted%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflabbergasted%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sometimes in UK **gobsmacked** is said but I don't like it.

Comment: 'Gobsmacked', as suggested by @WeatherVane, is a good synonym for 'flabbergasted', but is very BrE and not  very AmE.

Comment: I will point out that, in the US, the two words carry slightly different meanings/connotations, though I'm at a loss to explain it clearly and simply.

Comment: ***Gobsmacked***, adj. flabbergasted: struck dumb with awe or amazement. "I left the UK for the US more than 40 years ago. I first heard the word 'gobsmacked' about 10 years ago while visiting the UK. Perhaps because of the popularity of the programme Top Gear in the US, I now hear this used in the US." Duncan Connall, Rhode Island, US - http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-19929249

Comment: @A.Kvåle Sorry, I didn't intend my comment to be critical of you - just a fun way to point out that your source was mistaken.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: _"though it’s not particularly common in BrE either"_ Oh?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/flabbergast says otherwise too ...

Comment: ... and +1 for *gobsmacked*, which is synonymous in my idiolect, although it appears I misread the question and you want an Americanism, sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not compared to more neutral words like ‘surprised’, no. It’s not rare or anything, but can you honestly say you hear the word on a daily basis?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Not _daily_, but I don't hear "surprised" daily either. I'd say "flabbergasted" is plenty common, in the sense that everybody knows what it means and you will hear it once in a while.

Comment: @Lightness That was precisely what I meant by “not particularly common”. Everyone knows what it means, and you hear it ever so often, but it’s not exactly a _frequently_ used word. It’s infrequent enough that even if it were very rare in AmE, the overall difference wouldn’t be enormous.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I probably hear it about as often as I hear "enormous" ;)

Comment: That's really interesting. I don't know who these people being cited are but, as a Brit, the word "flabbergasted" is still very much in common usage over here, its just that the circumstances for its use tend to be fewer. I think, to us Brits, its difficult to imagine the word being used with an American accent and I have NEVER heard nor seen it used over there, and I have been all over the US. That, obviously, means nothing though. I do wonder, however, if it is used in specific parts of the US more than others. I can't imagine it has caught on in the Deep South, for example. I have said it o

Answer (score 13):

> I cannot really use it when it's an American talking, as the word is primarily used by British people.

Are you sure about this? I just ran a quick search and this is what I found:

- 440 hits —[Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (corpus contains 560 million words total)
- 44 hits —[British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (corpus contains 100 million words total)

The evidence indicates that American English uses the word **more often** than British English. Furthermore, if you look it up in pretty much [any dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flabbergast), it is not marked "chiefly British".

As an American, I can tell you that I would use "flabbergasted" and I do know what it means.

---

So, my answer is that the word you are indeed looking for is **flabbergasted**.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe "dumbfounded" would be more suitable to that sentence than flabbergasted.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer would be much better if you cited a reference for "dumbfounded".

Comment: I am rather flabbergasted (though not quite dumbfounded) to find that Ngram rates "dumbfounded" higher than "flabbergasted" in both US and British English.

Comment: .. but usage of both has dropped significantly in BrE. I have to wonder if this is due to a massive change in the type of material being published, though.

Comment: [citation](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/pitfalls-of-studying-language-with-google-ngram/)

Answer (score 0):

### I was floored

Figuratively, one has been dumbstruck and has fallen to the floor in shock or dismay.

Note that *floored* (definition two) uses the word *flabbergasted*.

Here is the definition from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/floored):

> **floor (one)**
>
> To cause one a great deal of shock, surprise, or disbelief.
> *Her accusations totally floored me. How on earth could she think that I had been stealing from the company?*

> **floored**
>
> 1. Shocked or flabbergasted.
>    *I was completely floored by Rob's declaration of love—I had no idea he felt that way about me!*
> 2. slang Struck and knocked to the floor.
>    *Can you believe that bully got floored by such a scrawny kid?*
> 3. slang Drunk. *Do you remember last night at the bar at all? You were really floored!*